# Having a variable in the JSON Tree

Tags: javascript, html, json, variables

I have a JSON file with a tree that changes depending on the input. For example, if I get the JSON for a value of "40" the path is result.40.neededNode.  I need to be able to get it in a format like

```
document.getElementByID("RandomID").innerHTML += ", " + result.(Variable).neededNode;
```

Is this possible to do?  Although I can do it in other languages, except PHP, I would rather have an answer in JavaScript

Comment: You can access it as `result[40]neededNode` (`var a = {40: {neededNode: 'f'}}; console.log(a[40].neededNode);` outputs `f`). I don't know if that answers your question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comment:

For a JSON of:

```
var a = {
   40: {
      b: 'c'
   }
}
```

you can access values for numerical keys using `[]`, as `a[40].b` will output 'c'. That doesn't limits to numerical keys though:

`a[40]['b']` outputs 'c' as well